# Exporting a Google Shopping feed with complex product types

Tags: configurable-product, bundle, third-party-module

There are a number of extensions available for creating Google Shopping data feeds, e.g. [this one from the Magento Core Team](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-content-api-for-shopping.html), and [this one from Wyomind](http://wyomind.com/data-feed-manager-magento.html).  What solution do you use for Google Shopping data feeds?

I'm particularly interested to hear experiences with complex products such as configurables and bundles.

Answer (score 1):

We're using Wyomind's Simple Google Shopping extension and most of our products are configurable products.

- When you use configurable products, you have to keep a couple things
  in mind: simple products that are associated to configurable products
  aren't individually visible, Wyomind's extension uses the parent
  product url for those simple products.
- you have to filter out the
  configurable products itself (since you only want each option to show
  up in the feed)

Comment: hi Erfan, Will you please give one example how each option we can bind in configurable product. it would be better if you will add some configuration tag here from Wyomind's Simple Google Shopping  extension..

Comment: @Erfan Can you think of any situation that would require to have configurable products in the feed? Amasty also seems to make it possible to get the url's and attributes from parent product when needed.

Comment: No reason to use configurable products in the feed @Webninja. My comment was just saying, if you use configurable products on your website, then the link will be for the configurable instead of the simple product as you might expect.

Answer (score 0):

I use the one from Wyomind on multiple sites, and it never fails. It has a great number of options for different product types, and is highly customisable. I use it for simple, configurable, grouped, and bundle products. Support is second to none too.

I've tried plenty of other extensions in the past, and none of them have come anywhere close.

Comment: I made some comparison and indeedn Wyomind's and also Amasty's feed extensions seem to have plenty of options. One of the big ones is the possibility to get the parent products data for simple products.